# The network patch was not found vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i Have a problem when i try to copy a file in a server folder. My code last week work great, but from nothing getting a error like that:

[image]

My code are that:

```
FileToCopy = strfilePath
NewCopy ="\\artfs02\07_ART_ECO\12_Samples\03_Samples_order\01_Samples_BOMs_&_DRW\" & strFileName
```

...

```
Try
                If System.IO.File.Exists(FileToCopy) = True Then
                    System.IO.File.Copy(FileToCopy, NewCopy, True)
                Else
                    LBL_ERR.Text = "There is no file to be copied !"
                    GC.Collect()
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                LBL_ERR.Text = "Failed to replace file! Parts were booked from Warehouse !"
                GC.Collect()
                Exit Sub
            End Try
```

Comment: Try accessing that path _manually_? Or try _pinging_ the path thru `cmd`? It's obvious in the message that there is a problem with the `path`.

Comment: When i try to accessing path manually work and the server has ping

Comment: Maybe the problem occurs during the concatenation of your directory. Try debugging your code and get the directory that your code produced, from there, try using that produced directory and see if you can access it.

Comment: Test Directory.Exists before the file copy and confirm that it exists in the scope of your application.